# Numpy segmented Sieve Of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes

For the segmented Sieve Of Eratosthenes, I have devised the following code provided. And I understand that it is not the best implementation; However, it should be much quicker than what it is now. The c Profile provides numerous results. However, it only defines built-in methods and gives no further context as to which built-in method is taking up the most time.
I wish to optimize this sieve to the maximum possible performance capable through python.

Which numpy built-in method is making my program slower?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cProfile
def generateprimes(n: int = 0) -> list:#simple sieve of Eratosthenes to find primes that make up
   #all factors of the upper bound.
   Primelist = np.full((1,int(math.sqrt(n) )),1, dtype='int8') 
   Primelist[0,0], Primelist[0,1] = 0,0
   for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(n))) + 1):
       if Primelist[0,i] == 1:
           for x in range (i*i,int(math.sqrt(n) ),i):
               Primelist[0,x] = 0
   indices = np.where(Primelist == 1)[1]
   return indices
   #unique, counts = np.unique(Primelist, return_counts=True)
   #dict(zip(unique, counts))
   #return [b for b in range(int(math.sqrt(n))) if Primelist[0,b] == 1]
def SegmentedSieve(R: int, L:int, Primes: tuple) -> tuple:
    Finalprime = np.empty((0,1), dtype = 'int32')
    limit = (R//L) # Total amount of segments
    Finalprime = np.append(Finalprime, Primes)
    for x in range(1, limit):
           Low = (L * x)
           High = Low + L
           Segment = np.full((1,High-Low),1,dtype='int8') #creates a segment that is the size of the differences between L and R
           NewPrimes = np.extract(Primes <= int(math.sqrt(High)),Primes) # Only taking the primes that are less than the square root of the upperbound. 
           #i.e the limit of the current segment
           for p in NewPrimes:
               s = ((int(math.ceil(Low / p))) * p) % Low # Finds the position of the first occurrence of the prime in the 
               # newest lowest bound or Low
               for i in range(s,L,p): # starts at the position found and skips every p distance. The upperbound is the 
                   #amount of elements in each segment.
                   Segment[0, i] = 0
           indices = np.where(Segment == 1)[1] + Low
           Finalprime = np.append(Finalprime, indices)
           continue
    return Finalprime




def main():
    R = (10 ** 7)
    L = int(math.sqrt(R))
    SegmentedSieve(R, L, generateprimes(R))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cProfile.run('main()')
```

[image: Run results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Performance

### `numpy.append`

The first thing I noticed is the `numpy.append` method with a cumulative time of 1.131s. For each of the 3162 times it is called a new array is created and the content of the existing array is copied. This can be improved by using a (builtin) list instead of a numpy array. Appending to a list is less expensive because lists are specifically designed to be appended to.

In order to still return a numpy array, the list of arrays `Finalprime` has to be converted to an array using the `numpy.hstack` method.

This change reduced the total runtime from 4.5s to 2.8s.

### Python `for` loop

Next I used the line based profile ["Scalene"](https://pypi.org/project/scalene/) to find out which code lines use up a lot of time.

This lead me to the following loop:

```
for i in range(s,L,p): # starts at the position found and skips every p distance. The upperbound is the 
    #amount of elements in each segment.
    Segment[0, i] = 0
```

All this loop does setting every pth element to zero. The same can be achieved using the arguments of the range function as a numpy slice instead:

```
Segment[0, s:L:p] = 0
```

This improvement further reduced the runtime from 2.8s to 1.0s

## General

There are a number things that are not performance related but are a bit odd:

- the `continue` keyword at the end of the main loop of `SegmentedSieve` is executed *every time at the end of the loop* and is therefor useless.
- Your code does not follow the [standard python formatting conventions](https://pypi.org/project/scalene/):

  - functions and variables should be named using `lower_snake_case` instead of `PascalCase`
  - after a comma there should usually be a space
  - before and after a top level definition there should be two blank lines
- Some of the type annotations are incorrect. `generateprimes` does not return a `list` but a numpy `array`. The `Primes` argument of the `SegmentedSieve` method is not a `tuple` but a numpy `array`. The same is true for the return value of said method.
- You are using 2D arrays for `Segment` and `Primelist` but the first dimension of these arrays has size 1 and it is never really used. This can be simplified to 1D arrays.

## Changed Code

This is the code with the performance and general suggestions applied to it:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
import math
import cProfile


def generateprimes(n: int = 0) -> NDArray[np.intp]:
    """
    simple sieve of Eratosthenes to find primes that make up
    all factors of the upper bound.
    """
    upper_bound = int(math.sqrt(n))

    primes = np.full(upper_bound, 1, dtype=np.int8)
    primes[0], primes[1] = 0, 0

    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(n))) + 1):
        if primes[i] == 1:
            for x in range(i**2, upper_bound, i):
                primes[x] = 0

    indices = np.where(primes == 1)[0]
    return indices


def segmented_sieve(r: int, l: int, primes: NDArray[np.intp]) -> NDArray[np.intp]:
    finalprime = []
    limit = r // l  # Total amount of segments
    finalprime.append(primes)

    for x in range(1, limit):
        low = l * x
        high = low + l

        # creates a segment that is the size of the differences between L and R
        segment = np.full(high - low, 1, dtype=np.int8)

        # Only taking the primes that are less than the square root of the upperbound.
        # i.e the limit of the current segment
        new_primes = np.extract(primes <= int(math.sqrt(high)), primes)

        for p in new_primes:
            # Finds the position of the first occurrence of the prime in the
            # newest lowest bound or Low
            s = (math.ceil(low / p) * p) % low

            # starts at the position found and skips every p distance. The upperbound is the
            # amount of elements in each segment.
            segment[s:l:p] = 0

        indices = np.where(segment == 1)[0] + low
        finalprime.append(indices)

    return np.hstack(finalprime)


def main():
    r = 10**7
    l = int(math.sqrt(r))
    segmented_sieve(r, l, generateprimes(r))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cProfile.run("main()")
```